# Event to Command behavior doesn't execute Command

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I'm using Event to Command Behavior found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior) to implement a command in the ItemTapped event of a ListView. I copied the EventToCommandBehavior and BehaviorBase classes to my project.

Here is my View

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppVentas.Behaviors"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="AppVentas.Views.UsuariosView">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView HasUnevenRows="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Usuarios}"
              ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">
        <ListView.Behaviors>
            <local:EventToCommandBehavior 
                EventName="ItemTapped" 
                Command="{Binding OpenChatCommand}"/>
        </ListView.Behaviors>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Nombre}"/>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And my ViewModel

```
public class UsuariosViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Usuarios> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public ICommand OpenChatCommand { get; set; }

    private UsuarioController usuarioController = new UsuarioController();

    public UsuariosViewModel()
    {
        Usuarios = new ObservableCollection<Usuarios>(usuarioController.Get().Where(i => i.Token == null));

        OpenChatCommand = new Command<Usuarios>(OpenChat);
    }


    void OpenChat(Usuarios usuario)
    {
        //trying to do something
    }
}
```

The problem is that OpenChatCommand never gets executed, the method OnEvent of the EventToCommandBehavior class do gets executed but the line Command.Execute (resolvedParameter); just doesn't do anything.

I'm using the PropertyChanged.Fody package if that's of any use.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Admittedly, I do not do a lot of frontend development (at least not in the last years), but if I am not mistake you are using the wrong "Change Interface". From the MicroSoft Docs :: "Notifies clients that a property value has changed." I looks like you are looking for an event handler instead. [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Reusable EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior), I suggest you can use Converter in your code, I create simple that you can take a look:

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="Listviewsample.MainPage"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Listviewsample"
xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Listviewsample.Behaviors"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <converter:TappedItemConverter x:Key="converter1" />
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout>
    <!--  Place new controls here  -->
    <ListView
        x:Name="listview1"
        HasUnevenRows="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding images}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding title}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.Behaviors>
            <local:EventToCommandBehavior
                Command="{Binding command1}"
                Converter="{StaticResource converter1}"
                EventName="ItemTapped" />
        </ListView.Behaviors>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<imagemodel> images { get; set; }
    public Command command1 { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        images = new ObservableCollection<imagemodel>()
        {
            new imagemodel(){title="image 1"},
            new imagemodel(){title="image 2"},
            new imagemodel(){title="image 3"}
        };
        command1 = new Command<imagemodel>(commandpage);

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
    private void commandpage(imagemodel m)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("the image model title is {0}",m.title.ToString());
    }


}

public class imagemodel
{
    public string title { get; set; }

}
```

The BehaviorBase.cs:

```
 public class BehaviorBase<T> : Behavior<T> where T : BindableObject
{
    public T AssociatedObject { get; private set; }
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(T bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);

        AssociatedObject = bindable;
        if (bindable.BindingContext != null)
        {
            BindingContext = bindable.BindingContext;
        }
        bindable.BindingContextChanged += OnBindingContextChanged;

    }



    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(T bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        bindable.BindingContextChanged -= OnBindingContextChanged;
        AssociatedObject = null;
    }
    void OnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnBindingContextChanged();
    }
    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        BindingContext = AssociatedObject.BindingContext;
    }

}
```

The EventToCommandBehavior.cs:

```
 public class EventToCommandBehavior : BehaviorBase<View>
{
    Delegate eventHandler;
    public static readonly BindableProperty EventNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create("EventName", typeof(string), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null, propertyChanged: OnEventNameChanged);

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null);

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty.Create("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null);

    public static readonly BindableProperty InputConverterProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Converter", typeof(IValueConverter), typeof(EventToCommandBehavior), null);

    public string EventName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(EventNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EventNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    public IValueConverter Converter
    {
       get { return (IValueConverter)GetValue(InputConverterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InputConverterProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(View bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        RegisterEvent(EventName);
    }
    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(View bindable)
    {
        DeregisterEvent(EventName);
       base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
    }



    void RegisterEvent(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            return;
        }

        EventInfo eventInfo = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent(name);
        if (eventInfo == null)
        {
           throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("EventToCommandBehavior: Can't register the '{0}' event.", EventName));

        }
        MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(EventToCommandBehavior).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("OnEvent");
        eventHandler = methodInfo.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this);
        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(AssociatedObject, eventHandler);
    }



    void DeregisterEvent(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (eventHandler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        EventInfo eventInfo = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent(name);
        if (eventInfo == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("EventToCommandBehavior: Can't de-register the '{0}' event.", EventName));
        }
        eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(AssociatedObject, eventHandler);
        eventHandler = null;

    }



    void OnEvent(object sender, object eventArgs)
    {
        if (Command == null)
        {
           return;
        }

        object resolvedParameter;
        if (CommandParameter != null)
        {
            resolvedParameter = CommandParameter;
        }
        else if (Converter != null)
        {
            resolvedParameter = Converter.Convert(eventArgs, typeof(object), null, null);
        }
        else
        {
            resolvedParameter = eventArgs;
        }

        if (Command.CanExecute(resolvedParameter))
        {
            Command.Execute(resolvedParameter);
        }

    }



    static void OnEventNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var behavior = (EventToCommandBehavior)bindable;
        if (behavior.AssociatedObject == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string oldEventName = (string)oldValue;
        string newEventName = (string)newValue;
        behavior.DeregisterEvent(oldEventName);

        behavior.RegisterEvent(newEventName);

    }

}
```

The Converter.cs,The Command property of the behavior is data bound to the command1 property of the associated ViewModel, while the Converter property is set to the TappedItemConverter instance, which returns the Tapped item of the ListView from the ItemTappedEventArgs.

```
 public class TappedItemConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var eventArgs = value as ItemTappedEventArgs;
        return eventArgs.Item;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is the sample at github, you can take a look:

https://github.com/CherryBu/Eventtocommand

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your bindingcontext is correctly set to an instance of UsuariosViewModel, the issue I see here is that you are not passing the command parameter. Your command accepts a Usuarios, but you need to pass that in via the CommandParameter property on the EventToCommandBehavior.

I also notice you have ListView_ItemTapped defined, but I'm not sure what you're doing in that method. It shouldn't be required to make the command work, but maybe you're using it for something else.